Problems trying to develop a stepper motor driver with TB6600
I am developing a stepper motor driver using the TB6600HG. However, when I plug the motor, all I hear is a faint buzzing sound, and the motor does not rotate. When I send commands to rotate, I can hear a subtle sound, but the motor still does not move.
This is the first time I am trying to develop my own hardware, I will post the schematic.
The stepper motor is a NEMA 23 model 23HS5628
What I have done so far:

Tested the motor with a driver I had already bought, and it worked perfectly.
Replaced the TB6600HG and got the same symptom.
Soldered the components onto a board, as I thought there might be a bad contact or interference on the breadboard, but the problem persisted.
Tested with different microstep configurations.

Could someone help me understand what might be happening? Did I design something incorrectly? What am I missing?


I have found that the problem I was facing was related to the poor 5V+ supply. Additionally, I connected Vreg to the decoupling capacitor only, and not to the 5V+. Those changes did the trick. Now the driver is working.
